# message script does't show in asp.net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below code to display the message details. Its work in all pages and it doesn't work in some places.  The below script does't work when am using calendar render event.Please help me to fix this error..

My partial code is here:

```
    finally
    {
        if (message != "")
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('List : \\n" + message + "');</script>", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so what?

Comment: there is no error here..

Comment: When you check the source on the result page, do you see the script?  Are you sure the message isn't an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

i think its may be because of no value in you 'message' variable. please try once by commenting the 'if' block/condition.